# Showing facet result even though not a single result found for solrQuery

Tags: solr

I'm Working with Solr 8.0.0 & i am facing the problem when using the exclude Tag

My solr query looks like below:

```
http://localhost:8984/solr/HappyDemo202/select?q=*:*&
rows=6&
start=0&
wt=json&
fq={!tag=CATFACET}cat:((desktops))&
fq={!tag=TAGFACET}tag:((cool))&
fq={!tag=Price}Price:[1200 TO 1245]&
json.facet={CatFacet:{type:terms,field:cat,domain:{excludeTags:CATFACET},limit:-1,sort:{count:desc}},TagsFacet:{ type:terms,field:tag,domain:{excludeTags:TAGFACET},limit:-1,sort:{count:desc}}}
```

**Output Of Query looks like below:**

```
{   "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*",
      "json.facet": "{CatFacet:{type:terms,field:cat,domain:{excludeTags:CATFACET},limit:-1,sort:{count:desc}},TagsFacet:{ type:terms,field:tag,domain:{excludeTags:TAGFACET},limit:-1,sort:{count:desc}}}",
      "start": "0",
      "fq": [
        "{!tag=CATFACET}cat:((desktops))",
        "{!tag=TAGFACET}tag:((cool))",
        "{!tag=Price}Price:[1200 TO 1245]"
      ],
      "rows": "6",
      "wt": "json"
    }  
    },   "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []   },   
 "facets": {
    "count": 0,
    "CatFacet": {
      "buckets": []
    },
    "TagsFacet": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "val": "new",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "val": "new1",
          "count": 1
        }
      ]
    }   } }
```

When you check the Output of Query,CatFacet is not showing any facet result because numFound is 0 but TagsFacet is showing the two facet result like new & new1. I don't know what going wrong , tagFacet must not show the two facet result if numFound is 0.

Can you please suggest,what's going wrong ? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: You're explicitly asking for the `fq` for tag to be excluded for the tag facet (`{excludeTags:TAGFACET}`) - meaning that if you didn't have that `fq` there, there would be results - and you're asking for a count without that field. If you want the counts to represent the actual result, don't exclude any filters.. but that may not be what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly asking for the fq for tag to be excluded for the tag facet (`{excludeTags:TAGFACET}`) - meaning that if you didn't have that fq there, there would be results - and you're asking for a count without that field.

If you want the facet to only count those documents being returned, drop the `excludeTags` value for all those facets that should only be returned for documents that are included in the result set.